# SQL update all varchar column row

Tags: mysql, sql, split, varchar

I have a table containing a single column containing varchar values. I want to update the column by splitting strings. For example, I have a table like this

```
'aaa/uuu', 'dfz/eza', 'sfd/aza'
```

I want to split all values by the character '/' in order to get this result

```
'aaa', 'dfz', 'sfd'
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: what database do you use? MS server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: I am using MYSQL database

Comment: MySQL what version? Also I did not know that MySQL has arrays...

Comment: What have you tried?  There are a ton of answers out there for splitting strings in mysql by a delimiter...

Comment: not array, I mean table

Comment: I am using mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
create table t(q varchar(255));

insert into t(q) values('abc/123');

update t
set q = SUBSTRING_INDEX(q, '/', 1);

select  SUBSTRING_INDEX(q, '/', 1)
from t;
```